# Limits to number of time a Fk is used in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

When my user adds an event for a specific client I get the following error:

```
ORA-12953: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 11 GB
```

Any other client works fine.

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: Is there any limit to number of times a PK is referenced through the child table referencing that PK ?

Comment: I do not see any relation between this question and the error message you pasted... But the answer is NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found problem , index was created on system table-space. Dropped index and recreated error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you hit the limit of Oracle 11g Express Edition, which limits user data size to 11GB. It has nothing to do with foreign keys, but the fact that you should consider buying Oracle Standard Edition license and upgrade your current database. Alternatively, remove some data if you don't need it any more.

Comment: Nope size is fine. I can add many other events with other clients.

Comment: If you say so ... though, Oracle disagrees.

Comment: Found problem , index was created on system table-space. Dropped it and recreated error goes away.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you fixed it!